How to make enumerate adjust to nested margin?
I have my own .cls class for taking notes during lectures. In there i have my own command for a theorem. Whenever i try to make a nested enumerate list it completely ignores the margin, putting the theorem title too far left. It's as if the enumitem list took precedence in determining where the entire theorem is on the page. How can i fix that?
My code looks sth like this:
\begin{de}[of an example]
    this is an example of how the indent should look
\end{de}

\begin{tw}[about how enumitem is keeping me up at night - ver. 1]
\begin{enumerate}
    % \item []
    \item 1
    \item 2
    \item 3
\end{enumerate}
\end{tw}

\begin{tw}
    just a reminder how the indentation should look
\end{tw}

\begin{tw}[about how enumitem is keeping me up at night - ver. 2]
\begin{enumerate}
    \item []
    \item 1
    \item 2
    \item 3
\end{enumerate}
\end{tw}

\begin{de}
    ugh
\end{de}

I use amsthm and have defined
\newtheoremstyle{my_tw}     
   {20pt} % spaceabove      
   {20pt} % spacevelow     
   {\itshape \leftskip = 15pt} % bodyfont     
   {-15pt} % indent     
   {\bfseries} % headfont     
   {.} % headpunctuation     
   {\newline} % headspace     
   {\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}\thmnote{ (#3)}} % headspec

And this is the outcome:

The first version is also annoying, there is no other way to make the list begin where it should. I am out of ideas, googling this yields nothing.
If i add any text between the beginning of the theorem and the list, it works just fine. But if i want to have just a list like this, it's an entire can of worms. The \item[] is there, because without it the code is in the same line as the header for some reason. Someone save me please

Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us how or where you've defined the tw and de environments. Are you using a package such as amsthm or ntheorem to define these environments?

@Mico Hi! I'm using amsthm and have defined both as
\newtheoremstyle{my_tw}     {20pt} % spaceabove      {20pt} % spacevelow     {\itshape \leftskip = 15pt} % bodyfont     {-15pt} % indent     {\bfseries} % headfont     {.} % headpunctuation     {\newline} % headspace     {\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}\thmnote{ (#3)}} % headspec (the de has no \itshape though, but otherwise they're the same)
It's in a .cls file that i refer to at the beginning of the document with \documentclass{}.

Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

You wrote, "there is no other way to make the list begin where it should." And where exactly should that be? I can't find it stated in your query.

turns out all you need to do is add
\leavevmode \vspace{-15pt}

right after the theorem header and label. Found it in amsthdoc.pdf in section 4.3.1
